# PayPal sandbox API 10055 Error?

Tags: php, authentication, paypal

I just created the necessary test accounts in the paypal sandbox site and trying to run a simple authentification test using the test code provided by paypal.

https://www.x.com/authentication-0

The documentation and interface of the sandbox site is terrible. I'm getting a 10055 error and I have no idea why.

```
ERROR Code: "10055"
Error Long Message: "This account is not approved for the authentication service. To enable this service, contact PayPal customer service"
```

** edit: Below is the auth credentials I'm using

```
//set APAPI URL
$url = trim('https://api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com/nvp');

//Create request body content
$body_data = array('USER' => "latte_1348034105_biz_api1.gmail.com", //TODO
                                'PWD' => "1348034127",
                                'SIGNATURE' => "Al1CQR.cOIPXCLTGUhSXLQykw2kZAbSHo-ZBaCu5MzRI4RhO5AUVTgyC", //TODO
                                'RETURNURL' => "http://localhost/AuthApiex/AuthReturnURL.php", //TODO
                                'CANCELURL' => "http://myCancelURL", //TODO
                                'LOGOUTURL' => "http://myLogoutURL", //TODO
                                'VERSION' => "3.300000",
                                'METHOD' => "SetAuthFlowParam");
```

Like I said I haven't changed anything in the sample code except for the credentials.

Comment: How did you created sandbox account. What is the sandbox URL you are hitting? Message is clear, your account is not authenticated. But for sandbox account, you need not to contact paypal customer service. Thus I guess you are not hitting `paypal sandbox` but real `paypal` site.

Comment: No the URL is set to the sandbox servers. Please check my edit.

Comment: Ahh remove your user, pwd, signature. You need not to post them in any case, not even for sandbox account. I'll also edit this comment later and remove lines till here. I worked with paypal in core php long ago but now a days using library in frameworks. I remember, with core PHP, it didn't worked for localhost but I need to put my code on test server, specially for IPN. Let me go through my old code.

Comment: Have you tested your request at http://quar.me/paypal/api/nvp_adaptive_payments/setauthflowparam or any other REST API tester? If it work there means problem with your code. If not, means problem with setting proper fields.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what's 'terrible' about

> "This account is not approved for the authentication service. To enable this service, contact PayPal customer service"

It tells you exactly what you need to do.
File a ticket with PayPal at https://www.paypal.com/mts and ask them to enable the Authentication Service on Sandbox account latte_1348034105_biz@gmail.com.

Any particular reason you're not using PayPal Access, by the way?
https://devportal.x.com/